# update to null if condition doesnt meet

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Original data

```
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| SeqNo |      Name      |   NameReason   |    NameDate    |
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|     1 | IronMan        | 'emptystring'' | 2019-03-01     |
|     2 | 'emptystring'' | 'emptystring'' | 'emptystring'' |
|     3 | IronMan        | 'emptystring'' | 'emptystring'' |
|     4 | IronMan        | A              | 'emptystring'' |
|     5 | 'emptystring'' | A              | 'emptystring'' |
|     6 | 'emptystring'' | 'emptystring'' | 2019-03-01     |
|     7 | IronMan        | A              | 2019-03-01     |
|     8 | 'emptystring'' | A              | 2019-03-01     |
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Required results:

```
+-------+----------------+------------+------------+
| SeqNo |      Name      | NameReason |  NameDate  |
+-------+----------------+------------+------------+
|     1 | NULL           | NULL       | NULL       |
|     2 | NULL           | NULL       | NULL       |
|     3 | NULL           | NULL       | NULL       |
|     4 | NULL           | NULL       | NULL       |
|     5 | NULL           | NULL       | NULL       |
|     6 | NULL           | NULL       | NULL       |
|     7 | IronMan        | A          | 2019-03-01 |
|     8 | 'emptystring'' | A          | 2019-03-01 |
+-------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

Query:

```
update #A
set NAME=NULL, NameReason=NULL, NameDate=NULL
where NAME<>'' OR NameReason=" OR NameDate <>''
```

From the query above, only done for SeqNo=7, how can i do for SeqNo8?

How can I update others row to null if doesn't meet the condition. 
For name: (only accept emptyString or character),
For nameReason: (only accept character),
For namedate: (only accept date).

Dealing with 10mils records, 30cols. Cannot be hardcode.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I update others row to null if doesn't meet the condition. For name: (only accept emptyString or character), For nameReason: (only accept character), For namedate: (only accept date).

You don't seem to care about name at all, because you're willing to accept it being either an emptystring or a not-emptystring

As such I think your update just needs to be:

```
update #A
set NAME=NULL, NameReason=NULL, NameDate=NULL
where NameReason=" OR NameDate=''
```

This could also be written as:

```
update #A
set NAME=NULL, NameReason=NULL, NameDate=NULL
where not (NameReason=" and NameDate='')
```

eg "null out every record where namereason or namedate is blank" / "null out every record that lacks a value in both namereason and namedate"

Comment: you're correct. How come i cant think of this idea. *facepalm* myself now.

Comment: Sometimes I look at a thing so long I can't see it either. Sometimes the answer comes to me while I'm writing the SO question explain myself clearly to another person. Sometimes it doesn't so I just hit post and wait for some pointers - I guess either way SO solves my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
Update #A
set NAME=NULL, NameReason=NULL, NameDate=NULL
where NAME='' OR NameReason='' OR NameDate = ''
```